# Detect delete key was pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

I'm writing a function that formats the entries on a `UITextField` to a date. It must be displayed like this dd/mm/yyyy. The problem is that I'm not being able to detect the delete key was pressed. I'm using `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to detect when the user presses a key. Is there something like a `\n` I may look for on the `replacementString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement string should be the empty string (`@""`) when a character is about to be deleted.